# Acumatica and notification template - strips html and other style tags - 2019 r1

Tags: acumatica

We are seeing issues where style tags and other markup is being stripped and modified within Acumatica's Notification templates when we save the template.

We have an email template coder coding out responsive cross client templates, and when we paste the code directly into the html editor, it strips out a lot of the code and markup.

Does anyone have any idea if there are restrictions or specific syntax that is need to work with notification templates? I have searched and read all that i could find.

For reference, we are on 2019 r1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have experienced the same before and ended up finding an alternate solution to get the result I needed. I recommend filing a support case with Acumatica.

Comment: You could probably force the HTML to be saved into the notification template table via SQL as well...

Comment: @Gabriel, I can't speak for Acumatica, but it may be their reason for doing this is to prevent their pages from breaking.  You can put HTML in activities as well and I've seen some very, very strange results from it.  It can completely reconstruct the parent form.